# javascript window closing after 15mins

Tags: javascript, timeout

Now, I have script that works, but only if time interval for closing is small (5mins works), but when I try to set timeout to 15mins, it fails every time. The script I'm using is:

```
function openClose(){
    my_window = window.open('http://www.somesite.com',
    "mywindow","status=1,width=1010,height=740");  //this should execute closepopup() after 15mins if my math is correct
    setTimeout(closepopup,900000); 
    }
    function closepopup(){
        if(false == my_window.closed){
            my_window.close();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: How it fails? What type of exception do you recive?

Comment: Your code seem ok to me too, I agree with dmitko, plz explain more how it fails. Try adding an alert("here") in closepopup function to debug and see if it's called.

Comment: @dmitko: it toesn't do anything, like it's not there... I already tried with alert and console.log, but nothing happens

Comment: Ive tested this code with a period of 5 seconds & 1 minute. Worked fine. Have you tested it with shorter intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought - could garbage collector dispose unwanted variables? I can see that `my_window` is a global one, try to persist timer variable as well:

```
timer = setTimeout(closepopup,900000)
```

Please, let me know if this works for you.